# CakePHP3: How to run custom SQL query in table model

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

In CakePHP 3, is it possible to run a custom SQL query from within a table model? If so, how?

I tried the following from within a table model:

```
public function getUsersByLocation($location)
{
    $sql = "SELECT `user_id`, `username` FROM `user` WHERE `location` = ?";
    $rows = $this->query($sql, [$location]);
}
```

(The query is deliberately simple for example purposes.)

But then, when I loop through the `$rows`, this results in an infinite loop.

I'm surprised CakePHP 3 does not clearly document running custom queries from a table model anywhere in their documentation. They are currently forcing users to use CakePHP's own numerous proprietary methods to glue together various queries.

Comment: There is simply no *point* in your case to use a custom query. It is in any case inferior to using the ORM directly. But it is very well documented [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#quick-tour) to do custom ones.

Comment: So from within a table model, I need to get the database connection (since it presumably was not passed in via dependency injection), and run the query on that? What an atrocious framework.

Comment: No, from withtin a table, you don't need to get the connection from the outside world, the connection is by default injected via the constructor, and can be accessed via the [**`Table::connection()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_connection) method (for tables this will by default return an instance of [**`\Cake\Database\Connection`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.Connection.html)). Maybe you should pay a little more attention to the docs of the oh so horrible framework that you are using.

Comment: And don't blame the framework if you are abusing things in a really bad way. In general: If you need to workaround sth you usually don't use the recommended best practice approach. The less lines, the better.

Comment: @mark Where in my example is anything being abused in a really bad way? If you have an elegant answer, please post it, and I will accept it. I would be glad to change my opinion on this framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
public function getUsersByLocation($location)
{
    $sql = "SELECT `user_id`, `username` FROM `user` WHERE `location` = ?";
    return $this->connection()->execute($sql, [$location])->fetchAll('assoc');
}
```

Comment: You can also just pull in the eloquent orm and use that directly instead of using the CakePHP orm. Since both are composer-compatible projects, this should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Great to hear that we think alike. As a CakePHP core developer, I hate to see our users complain about software when simple solutions are available to them. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

### So simply use php

```
$query = $this->find()
    ->select(['user_id', 'username'])
    ->where('location' => $location);
```

> within your Table class.

This is all documented very clearly in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html).